# html - Removing underline on anchor without CSS

Tags: html

Title says it all.

I'm well aware on how to do it with css but is there a way to remove the underline without using CSS ? (we're restricted on using CSS for this project)

Need to do it with pure html (no css, javascript, etc.).

Comment: AFAIK, links are formatted by default with blue and underlined, so you can't remove this formatiing without using CSS.

Comment: Add in-line styles to each link to disable the styling. It's technically not CSS

Comment: HTML defines a document markup. How could you define style without CSS or JS scripts that modify style? That's a lack of understanding about what you are trying.

Comment: Good luck achieving that!

Comment: @Alfabravo yup, i know.. tried telling that to the teacher and he ripped me a new one.. he said the CSS basics is a material for the next chapter and therefore is off limits (lmao) yet he's asking us to duplicate something that's probably using a css element.

Comment: Heh, that would mean misusing the HTML tags or changing how the browser renders a document. Either way, not a cool teacher :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first, you never said you were dealing with text. If you were, a *very* round-about way of doing it would be making the text an image instead and then linking the actual image.

Comment: Oops, my bad. So basically no way of just removing the text decoration itself with pure html?

Comment: No -- there is not a way to do that. The only way to do make it look that way is to implement the hack that I suggested above.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this with jQuery, but all links will be affected by this method.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a").css({"text-decoration": "none"});

});
```

If you only want to remove the `text-decoration` of certain links, I would use inline-styling.

Like this:

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Your link</a>
```

Comment: Any kind of css scripts are forbidden even inline ones.. basically css attributes/properties are off limits

Answer (score 1):

An inline style would be useful if you are limited to the CSS. Something like:

```
<a href="example.html" style="text-underline: none;">Link</a>
```

Another method would be to dynamically load a style with jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').css('text-underline','none');
    });
</script>
```

Ideally it would be better to do this in the CSS file but this can help.

Comment: jquery is also off limits.. need to do it with pure html

Comment: Then doing the inline style above the jQuery is the best and only way I can think of doing it.